# Nothing happen when Build and push IoT Edge model

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Nothing is happening when I do build and push from IoT edge module.

The deployment file manifest is generated, But the image are not build and push to azure container registry

DOCKER_HOST: 
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY: 
DOCKER_CERT_PATH: 
Additional Env Variables: 
------ Build and Push IoT Edge Modules started: Platform: Linux Amd64, Configuration: Debug ------
The deployment manifest is generated at C:\projects\poc\spikes\tmnaedge\tmnaedgeapp\config\deployment.amd64.debug.json
Finished Build and Push IoT Edge Modules.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to read the full tutorial (the solution described there is perhaps a bit more complex than yours) from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-machine-learning-edge-06-custom-modules

and for a shorter description on the next move, please read from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/tutorial-machine-learning-edge-06-custom-modules#build-publish-and-deploy-modules

Try to see what you are doing different.

hth